# SoundManager2 + iPhone - not loading sound

Tags: iphone, ios, html, soundmanager2

I am using SoundManager2 to play MP3 file on a HTML5 page. It works great on Desktop Safari, however it doesn't work on the iPhone. 
I run a debug console and I see that it doesn't load the file, it tries to load the file but in the network console the status of the file stays on "Pending".
Here is how I create the sound:

```
obj = soundManager.createSound({
                        id: path,
                        url: BOOK_PATH +  path,
                        useHTML5Audio: true,
                        preferFlash: false,
                        onload: function () {
                            //do stuff
                        }
                    });
```

Attached is a screenshot of the console. Stays on Pending... [image]

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I got the same problem and I'm still stuck on it, I wonder did you figure it out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [@Tomasz Nazar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11791949/soundmanager2-on-iphone-sound-not-playing-on-jquery-load) soundmanager2-on-iphone-sound-not-playing-on-jquery-load and also check Resources. Hope helpful

Comment: I thought that it only doesn't play sound until the user clicks, but I read the resources there and it turns out that ios also doesn't load until user interaction. Thanks.