# Html5 audio does not load/play even on click handlers

Tags: javascript, html, ios5, html5-audio, soundmanager2

I am using the following code to load sound on iPad Safari.

```
    var EI={sound:{}};
    EI.sound.load = function(){
        var preferFlash = true;
        if (Ext.os.is('iOS') && Ext.browser.is('WebKit'))
            preferFlash = false;
        // Load sound modules
        soundManager.setup({
            debugMode: true,
            preferFlash: false,
            onready: function(){
                var s = EI.sound; 
                s.audio = soundManager.createSound({
                    id: 'audio',
                    url: 'sound/sprite.mp3'
                });
                var opt = s.opt.online, f = opt.start+opt.duration, t=f+1500;
                if (s.enabled)  s.audio.play({from:opt.start, to:opt.start+opt.duration});
            }
        });
    }
```

The opt is defined as

```
EI.sound.opt = {
    "msg":{start: 53, duration: 701},
    "offline":{start: 1904, duration: 487},
    "online":{start: 3548, duration: 2476},
}
```

And a buttons `click` event handler looks like this,

```
handler: function(btn){
    EI.sound.load();
}
```

The problem is when the button is clicked the sound does not play. I am aware that Mobile Safari has limitation on html5 audio. These are steps that I took to over come it.

1. Only one file can be loaded. So I make an audio sprite and playing only some portion of it.
2. Sound can be loaded only on click or touchstart even handler. So I am loading on click event handler.

But still no sound. I expect to hear sound when I press that button. Its a splash image type button. Its the first button a user must have to press to use the application.

How can I make the audio play successfully?

Here are some resources

1. http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-ioshtml5/index.html
2. [SoundManager2 on iPhone - Sound not playing on jQuery Load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11791949/soundmanager2-on-iphone-sound-not-playing-on-jquery-load)

Answer (score 0):

You are using "EI.sound.load()" while you have to use "EI.sound.play()" or autplay: true in your soundmanager setup.